# Повреждаются данные в объекте

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть приложение (на Kotlin). Оно получает большой JSON-объект (2,5 мегабайта, маленький List в нем объекты с полями Float, String и большой List с объектами из Float, Date и Int) из API (Retrofit2 + OkHttp). В приложении это кэшируется в WeakReference внутри синглтона (простой кэш, чтобы не перезагружать данные, пока юзер переключает фрагменты).

Далее эти данные перебираются циклами (чтобы выбрать нужный кусок) и из этого куска заполняются вьюхи.

Проблема в том, что иногда, после нескольких перезагрузок некоторые цифры во втором объекте обнуляются или содержат какие-то случайные значения.

Пробовал отключать кэш, вьюхи, обновил com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson, проверял API. Баг повторяется снова и снова.

Почему значения в объекте могут принимать нулевые или случайные значения? В какую сторону следует копать? Может ли это быть проблема с памятью из-за того, что я работаю с большим объектом напрямую?

Comment: Скорее всего вы где-то их повреждаете сами. Immutable как принцип работы с данными вам поможет.